# Calling Gnuplot from php?

Tags: php, exec, gnuplot

I was trying to figure out how to use the exec command in my php script to call Gnuplot.

First, I'll give some background context:

I've written a few php files that grabs data from a database and puts the recorded values into text files in such a way that they can be read by gnuplot. From there I have a second php file that generates a gnuplot script that has the proper pointers to create the graph.

I can manually go to c:/gnuplot/gnuplot/binary/gnuplot.exe graph.txt and generate the graph manually, but I can't figure out how to automate it.

Both Linux and Windows suggestions would be helpful! I'm writing it and testing it on windows, but once it's fixed it is going to our Linux server.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think in such a case it might be easier to try it already in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute gnuplot on a Linux Machine, you can use the [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function in php. I am not sure what exactly u want to do with the output, but exec can definitely run the program.

Comment: Put them in a directory or something, that won't be a problem once I get them generated. I assumed it would be, considering how heavily (forgive the wording) "linuxy" gnuplot is.

Answer (score 2):

This is some **very** old code I wrote to get PHP to talk to gnuplot, so long ago that it didn't even support PNG output at the time, hence the use of netpbm. This hasn't been tested on Windows:

```
// Assuming data has been written to $data_file...

$image_file = tempnam("/tmp","gnuplotout");
$gplot_start = date("y/m/d", $start_date);
$gplot_finish = date("y/m/d", $finish_date);
$gnuplot_cmds = <<< GNUPLOTCMDS
set term pbm color small
set output "$image_file"
set size 1, 1
set title "Title"
set xlabel "Date"
set ylabel "EUR"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%y/%m/%d"
set xrange ["$gplot_start":"$gplot_finish"]
set format x "%d/%m"
set nokey
plot "$data_file" using 1:2 with lines
GNUPLOTCMDS;
$gnuplot_cmds .= "\n";

// Start gnuplot
if(!($pgp = popen("/usr/bin/gnuplot", "w"))){
    # TODO Handle error
    exit;
}
fputs($pgp, $gnuplot_cmds);
pclose($pgp);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
passthru("/usr/bin/pnmtopng $image_file");

// Clean up and exit
unlink($data_file);
unlink($image_file);
exit;
```